# Python handling multiple set-cookie headers from string to dict

Tags: python, http

I have a simple API that returns a `dict` of some HTTP data. One of these values is a `string` of response headers.

For example, if I do a Get request to the [CPython GitHub repo](https://github.com/python/cpython) it returns:

```json
{
   "X-Github-Request-Id":"C7BD:9E95:372D0F:4313C3:6105B2CF",
   "Date":"Sat, 31 Jul 2021 20:30:08 GMT",
   "Etag":"W/\"09c9960a9944661ce7a432406093a854\"",
   "Strict-Transport-Security":"max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload",
   "X-Frame-Options":"deny",
   "Server":"GitHub.com",
   "Permissions-Policy":"interest-cohort=()",
   "X-Xss-Protection":"0",
   "Expect-Ct":"max-age=2592000, report-uri=\"https://api.github.com/_private/browser/errors\"",
   "Accept-Ranges":"bytes",
   "Cache-Control":"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate",
   "Referrer-Policy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade",
   "Content-Security-Policy":"default-src \"none\"; base-uri \"self\"; block-all-mixed-content; connect-src \"self\" uploads.github.com www.githubstatus.com collector.githubapp.com api.github.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com github-production-repository-file-5c1aeb.s3.amazonaws.com github-production-upload-manifest-file-7fdce7.s3.amazonaws.com github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com cdn.optimizely.com logx.optimizely.com/v1/events translator.github.com wss://alive.github.com *.actions.githubusercontent.com wss://*.actions.githubusercontent.com online.visualstudio.com/api/v1/locations insights.github.com; font-src github.githubassets.com; form-action \"self\" github.com gist.github.com; frame-ancestors \"none\"; frame-src render.githubusercontent.com render-temp.githubusercontent.com viewscreen.githubusercontent.com; img-src \"self\" data: github.githubassets.com identicons.github.com collector.githubapp.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com secured-user-images.githubusercontent.com/ *.githubusercontent.com; manifest-src \"self\"; media-src github.com user-images.githubusercontent.com/; script-src github.githubassets.com; style-src \"unsafe-inline\" github.githubassets.com; worker-src github.com/socket-worker-3f088aa2.js gist.github.com/socket-worker-3f088aa2.js",
   "Set-Cookie":"_gh_sess=ursWeM%2FMN6%2FL%2BjF%2BgDfUG%2F0x%2Bn8N9gfsUZwkH46aVuhBz1k68CGcM4Y0nO2YQZDobo6K4h3yKRDvCf3VOXWQuss9bTmbnJUIbBCxyfjIp51X8aY6yMAsetNb3VfAcX%2FyLutI1PxqW1rZwBMdBdZI%2B1cVIMhBycZ5eH2JP28XgrWhvwDbYY5R8iOeNAlKI%2BUSJumK%2FYxaBBDqvGy8wq%2B86GUJZ0AyJT9XDpjC6anjobSsXoKFSlO9duMHwUjzig%2Fc9JIuDzV8t5c4lXMVAw3Pww%3D%3D--BgOjVEZOsOlgpJzW--x%2B9DXfO%2Bgn7HhJAXmKrhag%3D%3D; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Lax",
   "Set-Cookie":"_octo=GH1.1.366237382.1627763408; Path=/; Domain=github.com; Expires=Sun, 31 Jul 2022 20:30:08 GMT; Secure; SameSite=Lax",
   "Set-Cookie":"logged_in=no; Path=/; Domain=github.com; Expires=Sun, 31 Jul 2022 20:30:08 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Lax",
   "Content-Type":"text/html; charset=utf-8",
   "Vary":"X-PJAX, Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With",
   "X-Content-Type-Options":"nosniff",
   "Content-Encoding":"gzip"
}
```

Note the multiple `Set-Cookie` headers.

I want to convert this to a Python `dict` type. To do this though I would need to merge the `Set-Cookie` headers. I can join these headers with the `;` character, but I'm unsure what the best way to do this would be?

I have searched through the requests and urllib3 source to see how they do it but to no luck.

The API will return other values like, but not limited to `status code (string), URL (string), headers (string of JSON)`.

As stated I could use the [EmailMessage class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage), like urllib3. But, I'm still unsure how to go from the string to this. I can't turn it into a dict as that will then remove all but one of the duplicate headerrs.

Comment: What kind of object does this API return that is not a `dict` but has multiple values with the same key? How would you go about accessing those? Is the entire code block you posted just a simple string?

Comment: It returns like status code etc. and yeah it's just a string. I'll update the q to make it clearer @MarcoBonelli

Comment: I don't belive this question should be closed as although the question stated is similar. It doesn't help me go from this string to a point where I have key, value pairs.